# Uploading stickers/gifs/etc. directly from Gboard (Mobile Keypad) in Ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4, giphy

Like in `WhatsApp`, **stickers/gifs/etc**. can be sent from `Gboard(Mobile keypad)`. So, how to allow sending **stickers/gifs**..etc. in `Ionic Application (Ionic 3/4)`?

Is there any plugin available or any other way to handle `Gboard` insertion?
Please suggest.

Mobile image:

[image: screenshot 1]

On my chatpage, simple textmessages (with emojis as well) can be sent; but not Gboard's gifs/stickers..etc through textarea.

```
    <textarea [(ngModel)]="currentMessage" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" placeholder="Type Message..." id="messageInputBox"></textarea>
```

Comment: I am trying to add GIF from keypad so I am getting error like this app is not supporting image assertion here. You will get same?

Comment: Add your code for contributors reference

Comment: @PareshGami Yes. I am getting the same message "This text field doesn't support stickers."

Comment: @MohanRajS I've added my input box code snippet. Please suggest.

Comment: I've placed a [feature request on Capacitor's github](https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/3048), lets follow it